# Enabling wireguard log messages with secure boot / kernel lockdown enabled

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wireguard

On fedora 37, I am trying to enable kernel log messages for wireguard by executing this command in a root-shell:

```
echo module wireguard +p > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error: `operation not permitted: /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`.

I can see in dmesg that the reason for this error is: `debugfs access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7`.
Kernel lockdown is automatically enabled due to secure boot being enabled.

Is there any other way to enable the wireguard log messages with secure boot / kernel lockdown enabled, e.g. via kernel cmdline or modprobe options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To temporary enable wireguard kernel log messages, execute:

```
sudo modprobe -r wireguard && sudo modprobe wireguard dyndbg
```

reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html#debug-messages-at-module-initialization-time

You can view the log message with `sudo dmesg -T --follow | grep wireguard`

If you want to permanently enable wireguard kernel log messages, create a modprobe configuration `/etc/modprobe.d/wireguard.conf` with content `options wireguard dyndbg` and execute `sudo modprobe -r wireguard && sudo modprobe wireguard`

Comment: This results in `wireguard: unknown parameter 'debug' ignored` in dmesg.

Comment: Im kinda lost then, maybe disable secure boot or build a costum kernel or request the wireguard dev to provide a module for your demand

Comment: It works with `options wireguard dyndbg` :) 

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html#debug-messages-at-module-initialization-time

If you update your answer, I'll accept it :-)

Comment: To temporary enable wireguard debugging: `sudo modprobe -r wireguard && sudo modprobe wireguard dyndbg`

Comment: great, done :))